# How can I make all fonts show a sample string for comparison?

Tags: fonts

For a specific task I want to select a decent font. For that I want to compare the text “E G PM” for all my installed fonts (or even more). Especially the bold face of a font (if it has any) will more likely match my requirements.

**A quick visual viewing will probably sort 90% out already, so I was thinking of seeing a list of my string in the different font faces available on my system.**

The font viewer/manager I tried are not up for the task. Which app could help me here or how can I quickly solve my problem otherwise?

The apps I tried are:

- fontmatrix (binary from trusty sources installed on bionic)

  - version 0.6.0+svn20110930 (0.9.99)
  - a bug hinders your configured text to be shown (font name is always shown)
  - it does not show the bold face of a font in the list (just regular)
- gnome-specimen (also from trusty)

  - you have to add each font face individually (2-3 clicks) to seem them
  - you see substituted fonts (if glyph is not in font) without being warned/told
- fontypython crashes at startup
- fontmanager.app is unusable in i3
- gwaterfall

  - text is fixed to “Lazy dog...”
  - needs each font selected individually (4 clicks at least)
- font-manager

  - has a great browse mode, but in that mode it doesn’t show your own text (only font name)
- gnome-font-viewer can’t set text
- typecatcher

  - custom text, yes
  - shows just regular type face for each font (i.e. not bold or others)
  - requires 1 click to see the font
  - doesn’t show system fonts(?), only a big selection of downloadables
- Opcion

  - horrible user interface
  - doesn’t show bold type face (and others) in the list
- FontViewer

  - makes fonts look ugly (doesn’t antialias or whatnot)
  - no list, no bold face
- kfontview

  - doesn’t find system fonts itself (select font with “Open...” on a font file)
  - doesn’t do lists of fonts
- FontBase

  - is the best one so far...
  - shows “google fonts” (so many; chances high to find something useable?)
  - adding `/usr/share` as font directory turns the program slow
  - shows custom text for all font faces; easy to scroll
  - (clicking the wrong button activates all fonts with no way to return to your selection from before → not a good mechanism to mark fonts for future reference)

Answer (score 3):

There is `gnome-terminal` when you select `Edit` -> `Profile Preferences` -> `Custom Font`:

[image: terminal fonts.png]

However on my system it doesn't display the "E G PM" even though it head fakes you into thinking it will.

Comment: The gnome font selector... On my system `gnome-terminal` restricts the selection to mono space fonts. I found the same selector in `gnome-tweaks` (there are more examples). The sample string is applied to the sample string input box itself (only).

Comment: @RobertSiemer It certainly isn't the greatest display of fonts. But I like it better than LibreOffice Writer (another default application in Ubuntu) which I found surprisingly awkward. I think a nifty app would be to loop through every font family and print a sample sentence / string to your printer. Sometimes printed copies aren't faithful to what you see on the screen (WYSIWYG)

Answer (score -1):

here below is a small macro for libreoffice which will ask you a sample sentence, and generate an exemple file with that sentence printed with all the fonts installed in your system, with the fonts name.
Pretty usefull !

Just copy and run it as a macro in an empty LibreOffice Writer document.
Regards.

```
'********************************************************************************
'Copyright (C) 2003 Laurent Godard - adaptation légère P. Quaglia 2021
'dev.godard@wanadoo.fr

'This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
'modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
'License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
'version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

'This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
'but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
'MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
'Lesser General Public License for more details.
'http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-license.php

'You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
'License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
'Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA
'******************************************************************************

Sub ListingPolicesSystem()

'**Sub Macro1 

phrase=InputBox("phrase de test :","Liste des polices","Voix ambiguë d'un cœur qui, au zéphyr, préfère les jattes de kiwis.") 

oText=thisComponent.getText() 
oCursor = oText.createTextCursor() 

'Liste des fontes 

Dim oToolkit As Object 
oToolkit = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.awt.Toolkit") 
Dim oDevice as Variant 
oDevice = oToolkit.createScreenCompatibleDevice(0, 0) 
Dim oFontDescriptors As Variant 
oFontDescriptors = oDevice.FontDescriptors 
Dim oFontDescriptor As Object 

thiscomponent.lockcontrollers 
oCursor.string="Liste des polices installées sur le système"+chr(10)+chr(10)
valide=oCursor.gotoEnd(false)
for i= LBound(oFontDescriptors) to UBound(oFontDescriptors) 
    oCursor.CharFontName=oFontDescriptors(i).Name 
    oCursor.string=cstr(i)+". "+oFontDescriptors(i).Name+"  : " 
    valide=oCursor.gotoEnd(false) 
    oCursor.string=phrase+chr(10)
    valide=oCursor.gotoEnd(false) 
next i 
thiscomponent.unlockcontrollers 

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is a neat idea (and did not downvote), but it failed when I tried it - with an error BASIC runtime error.  Property or method not found: getText.

Comment: When I use Version: 7.6.4.1 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 60(Build:1) on Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic, the macro works perfectly (It took a while to process +1700 fonts but that seems to be expected).